# xcode 4 copy resources on a device only once

Tags: ios, xcode, build, resources, copy

I have a question about the copy phase of resources with xCode. I have an app very heavy, (about 1gb, lot of pngs) and I wanted to know if it is possible to copy all resouces on device only once ? Because, when I change some lines of my program and I make an another build, xCode copy again all resources...but they are not change.

There are an option for skip the copy phase on device or make it only once?

Thanks

Xcode 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, here is an XCode hack that worked for me:

1. Build the app once correctly then all the resources will get copied onto the device
2. Delete the "Copy Resources" build phase from the target
3. Do a clean (even though you deleted the build phase all the resources still exist in the build folder and get uploaded to the device on execution)
4. do a "Run" (this will just upload the files in the build folder to the correct location on the device, leaving the resources from step one in place and just uploading the binary)
5. Whenever you want to upload resources just "git checkout" your xcodeproj to revert your changes and go back to step one, make sure not to check in your changes to the project)

Beware, you are crippling the build process, you might introduce local bugs if used incorrectly.

Comment: Most of my resources are in a single bundle, so I was able to just remove that one resources.bundle item from the Copy Resources phase.